# JSON update array inside of object

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

Here's what my JSON response looks like:

```
"_id" : 537,
    "quizzes" : [
        {
            "wk" : 1,
            "score" : [
                10
            ]
        },
        {
            "wk" : 2,
            "score" : [
                8
            ]
        },
        {
            "wk" : 3,
            "score" : [
                5
            ]
        },
        {
            "wk" : 4,
            "score" : [
                6
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to update the score array inside one of the objects, here's my attempt at it:

```
db.collection('connect').update({_id: id}, {$push: { quizzes[0]: { score: 89  }  }});
```

Comment: What would be the expected result? If you wish to update the score array so that it still remains a single element array then consider using the update operator modifier `"$set": { 
            "quizzes.0.score.0": 89    
        }` as mentioned in my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
db.collection('connect').update({_id: id}, {$set: { "quizzes.0.score":89}  })
```

A better way to do it is to not reply on the index of the quizzes array and use the "wk" attribute

```
db.collection('connect').update({_id: id,quizzes:{$elemMatch:{"wk":1}}}, {$set: { quizzes.$.score: 89  }  }})
```

Comment: The brackets are giving me a syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: $ is the positional operator. Which replaces the hard coded 0 in the previous query

Comment: That seems to not be working for me, can you check this question I posted? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30961717/json-update-array-based-on-name-value?noredirect=1#comment49955636_30961717

Answer (score 2):

Try the following update:

```
db.collection("connect").update(
    {
        "_id": id            
    }, 
    {
        "$set": { 
            "quizzes.0.score.0": 89    
        }
    }
);
```

which uses the **[dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation)** to access the elements of an array and to access the fields of an embedded document.

> To access an element of an array by the zero-based index position,
>   concatenate the array name with the dot (.) and zero-based index
>   position, and enclose in quotes:

```
'<array>.<index>'
```